# OpenCV Perspective Transform giving unexpected result

Tags: python, opencv, transformation

I am trying to transform from a trapezoid (in the first image) to a rectangle (in the second image), but getting a strange result (in the third image).

[image]

My plan was to use a perspective transform, defined by the four corner points of the trapezoid and the four corner points of the rectangle.

In this example, for the trapezoid they are:

```
ptsTrap = [[  50.          100.        ]
           [  50.          200.        ]
           [ 250.           64.73460388]
           [ 250.          235.26539612]]
```

and for the rectangle:

```
ptsRect = [[  50.  100.]
           [  50.  200.]
           [ 250.  100.]
           [ 250.  200.]]
```

I am getting a perspective transform from these points:

```
T = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ptsTrap, ptsRect)
```

And then building the image from that:

```
arrTrapToRect = cv2.warpPerspective(arrTrap, T, arrTrap.shape[:2])
```

However, as you can see from the image, this isn't giving the expected transformation.

I can't seem to work out why even the points that defined the transform are not being projected according to it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your methodology is correct. The problem arises when you specify the coordinates of your corner points. I don't know how you calculated them, but you have swapped your X and Y axes. This is reflected in the transformation applied to your final image. I find the corner points to be:

```
ptsTrap = [[[  99.   51.]]
           [[  64.  251.]]
           [[ 234.  251.]]
           [[ 199.   51.]]]

ptsRect = [[[ 102.   49.]]
           [[ 100.  249.]]
           [[ 200.  250.]]
           [[ 200.   50.]]]
```

Finding the perspective transform from these points gives the correct result:
[image: Perspective Transform result]

For reference, this is the code I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_corners(image):
    im = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)

    cnt = cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
    cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt[0], 5, True)
    return cnt.astype(np.float32)

def main(argv):
    trap = cv2.imread('trap.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    rect = cv2.imread('rect.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    ptsTrap = find_corners(trap)
    ptsRect = find_corners(rect)

    T = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ptsTrap, ptsRect)

    warp = cv2.warpPerspective(trap, T, rect.shape[:2])

    cv2.imshow('', warp)
    cv2.imwrite('warp.png', warp)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem.  I was building the images myself, and I made the silly mistake of treating x,y as i,j instead of j,i.  Looks good now!